# POST params are not passes from my reverse proxy to my backend server

Tags: node.js, nginx, post, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx server which provides static web content and a reverse proxy which exchange with my backend API.
I configured with certbot my SSL certificate.
My problem is that the POST params are not passed from my reverse-proxy t my backend server.
My GET params are retrieved properly.

I've logged my POST request in Nginx
"POST /Users/signup HTTP/2.0" 500 1181 "https://MYDNS/signup" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" [{\x22username\x22:\x22testet\x22}]

My nginx configuration file

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name MYDNS;
    root /var/www/MYDNS;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDNS/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDNS/privkey.pem;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/MYDNS.error.log warn;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/MYDNS.postdata-access.log post_logs; 

     location /Users {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }

    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name MYDNS;

    return 301 https://MYDNS$request_uri;
    }
```

In my backend server 
in my app.js file

```
     var Users =require('./routes/Users');
     app.use('/Users',Users);
```

In my routes/Users.js file

```
     router.post('/signin', function (req, res, next) {
     console.log(req.params.username); --> undefined
     console.log(req.body.username); --> undefined
     });
```

I also tried to change 
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001 to 
proxy_pass http://localhost:3001

On my server, I've tested

```
    curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "this_is_param_1"}' http://localhost:3001/Users/signin
```

but the result is the same.
Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake and disable bodyParser in my backend server
It's OK now